# Android Studio Not install [Linux] pop os 20.04

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

when I run `flutter doctor`
I get following message: as well I cannot run `flutter run` since it is not able to find running emulators.

```
❯ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at
      /home/ajinkya/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (3 weeks ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09
      -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/ajinkya/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).


Scanning for devices is taking a long time...⣽
```

But I have all installed already:

[image]

Comment: ❯ adb devices
zsh: command not found: adb

Answer (score 0):

The issue was during multiple JAVA version. and correct PATH was not set.

Even after setting correct version from `sudo update-alternatives --config java` would not set JAVA version.

entering `javac -version` would print version 11.

SET your PATH like below `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH="/usr/lib/dart/bin:$PATH"
```

And then this would print correct:

```sh
❯ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_265
```